# Why is Chrome sending me to the Google homepage when I try to search?

Tags: google-chrome, search

A few days ago, Google Chrome started acting up. Whenever I <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for a new tab, enter some search terms and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I'm taken to a blank Google homepage with [this URL](https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS440US440&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=hea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1): `https://www.google.com/webhp?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enUS440US440&sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=hea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1`.

This happens with one-word and multi-word search terms, and with any of the operators I use regularly. It also happens when I try to search in the url/search bar of an existing tab.

Running Chrome 16.0.912.75 m on Windows 7 Pro SP1. I hadn't installed any new extensions for several weeks before this started happening. As far as I can tell, nothing has changed.

Comment: Given the URL, could it be [this](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=177873)? What happens when you disable it?

Comment: @Daniel I enabled Instant search and the weirdness has stopped happening. Problem solved but not explained. Twist: instant search was happening for me before with omnibox search - and now that I've clicked "enable", it's *not*.

Comment: URLs that look like this are originally called from the URL bar search, and then either (with JS) "redirected" to an anchor, or (without JS) redirected to a URL that contains the query as a regular parameter. Somehow this seems to be not working for you. What happens when you toggle the preference, does the problem occur again?

Comment: @Daniel I toggled the preference back off and the strange behavior disappeared. I am still not seeing any Instant activity when I switch the preference back on, however.

Comment: Instant seems to be broken in current Chrome versions, from what I can gather from web pages. It doesn't work for me either. Since I don't use Chrome except for answering questions on SU, I can't tell you more. Since toggling the preference fixed it, it was probably a partially broken preference file that now was re-written, or something similar.

Comment: @Daniel sounds good to me. Care to throw this info in an answer?

Comment: I am curious if the Chrome blog has this listed as an 'error' or a 'feature'...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given the URL you posted, it might be related to the [Instant Search](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=177873) feature of Chrome. It doesn't work for me and, according to some web searches about it, others.

Toggle the preference and see what happens.

> [image]

In case you have a corrupted preferences file (you could test this with a pristine Chrome profile by specifying the [`--user-data-dir` command line parameter](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)), this should cause Chrome to overwrite it.

Comment: I had the same problem today at both work and home (I assume because my settings are sync'd). Toggling the instant search option seemed to fix it (started and ended with it off).

Answer (score 1):

I created a "new" custom search engine using the below url. It allowed me to maintain the predictive search, but made the omnibox search work again (this issue is back as of yesterday, 06/16/14, for me).

https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%s

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about how to use the custom engine? (How to add it to Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me and for some reason disabling "User-Agent Switcher for Chrome" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer from Daniel Back already said, it's an problem with the suggest feature. You can fix this with going to:

```
chrome://flags
```

and set the "#answers-in-suggest" flag to activate.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed this problem:
I went to Preferences, Google Instant predictions
Shows this:
When should we show you results as you type?

1. Only when my computer is fast enough.
2. Always show Instant results.
3. Never show Instant results.

I switched it from 1 to 2 and saved my changes.

Everything back to normal! Now when I search in google, it does not bring me to another google page, but the results page I was looking for. Hope this helps!